# How to render only one component after changing its state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I display only one `<CardDetails />` component, whose parent was clicked? When I run my code, after changing the state all my CardDetails components render. Is there another way instead of adding unique onclick event and state for every component?

```
class Deck extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        cardDetails: false
      };
      // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }
    onClick() {
      this.setState({
        cardDetails: true,
        // when cardDetails is set as true, all <CardDetails /> components are rendered
      }, function() {
        console.log('cardDetails: ' + this.state.cardDetails + '. This.onclick: ' + this.onClick)
      });
    }
    render() {
        return ( < div className = "deck-container" > < div className = "chosen-cards" > 
        <CardHistory onClick = {
              this.onClick
            } > {
              this.state.cardDetails ? < CardDetails / > : null
            } < /CardHistory> 
            < CardHistory onClick = {this.onClick} > {
              this.state.cardDetails ? < CardDetails / > : null
            } < /CardHistory> </div > < /div> );}}
            ReactDOM.render( < Deck > < /Deck>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a shouldComponentUpdate method in CardDetails component. Also send the state value as props to it. then do something like

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return (nextprops.cardDetails != this.props.cardDetails);
}
```

Basically this will prevent re rendering of the CardDetails component whenever the state is changed.

Comment: Did I get you right that I should add that `shouldComponentUpdate` method to `class CardDetails extends React.Component {}` and change from this.state.cardDetails to this.props.cardDetails? I'm new to react and its going a little bit slow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep the parent component as it is. While declaring <CardDetails /> Declare <CardDetails cardDetails = { this.state.cardDetails } /> So that inside card details component you can access this.props.cardDetails. So any change in parent component will change the props value thereby re rendering CardDetails component. You can prevent re rendering by returning false in card details component. So when do you want to not to render is when the props.cardDetails value changes.

Comment: Yeah, but it still renders multiple all the components with <CardDetails />. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: I mean that there are 7 components with `CardDetails` components as children and when I click on one, this one's <CardDetails> should be rendered.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question previously. You are having a set of names like CardDeatils1, CardDetails2... till 7. On clicking one you need to mount or load your component right ?

Comment: Yep, but I didnt name them like CardDetails1, CardDetails2. And they live in parent component. When I click on a parent component. state cardDetails is changing to true and CardDetails rendered. And when I clicked on one parent, this parent's CardDetails component should be rendered.

Comment: This is how CardDetails and its parent look like

Comment: You can make each component to aware of state changes in different way. So I would recommend whenever you are dealing with multiple components or multiple component, make state aware of which one is clicked rather than toggling onclicked or not.